# Define one-to-many and one-to-one relationship on the same tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-6.0

I am trying to create the following models in c# but am getting this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to determine the
> relationship represented by navigation 'Activity.Token' of type
> 'Token2'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this
> property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using
> 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.'

Here are my 2 models

```
public class Token2
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(LastActivity))]
    public long? LastActivityId { get; set; }

    public Activity? LastActivity { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Activity>? Activity { get; set; }
}

public partial class Activity
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Test { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(Token2))]
        public long? TokenId { get; set; }

        public Token2? Token { get; set; }
    }
```

So the idea is that a Token has many activities related to it and I also want to keep that of the last activity acted on the Token.

And activity might be related to a Token or not, this is optional

How can i define this in EFCore?

Comment: Can you please share the desired tables schema?

Answer (score 1):

First Tip : Avoid using annotion Because in your case your entities Will be strongly depending on EF

Your Activity Entity :

```
public partial class Activity
{

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Test { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public long? TokenId { get; set; }

    public Token? Token { get; set; }
}
```

the Token class

```
public class Token
{

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Activity? LastActivity
    {
        get
        {
            return Activities .OrderByDescending(q => q.Date).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
    public ICollection<Activity>? Activities { get; set; }
}
```

And the configuration to add your on OnModelCreating Method

```
public class TokenConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Token>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Token> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(a => a.Id);
        builder.HasMany(q => q.Activities).WithOne(q => q.Token).HasForeignKey(q => q.TokenId);
      
    }
}
public class ActivityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Activity2>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Activity2> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(a => a.Id);
       

    }
}
```

Comment: `Activities .OrderByDescending(q => q.Date).FirstOrDefault()` relies on either lazy loading enabled or user eager/explicitly loading/including  `Activities` in the request which is doubtful choice.

Comment: We can build a linq query to retrieve last Activity instead of retrieving All the list

Answer (score -1):

[ForeignKeyAttribute's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute) :

> The annotation may be placed on the foreign key property and specify the associated navigation property name, or it may be placed on a navigation property and specify the associated foreign key name.

If you add ForeignKeyAttribute on the foreign key property `Activity.TokenId`, then you need specify the navigation property name `Activity.Token` (not the type `Token2`) like :

```cs
public partial class Activity
{
    ...
    
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Token))]
    public long? TokenId { get; set; }
    
    public Token2? Token { get; set; }
}
```

But the question example follow [the navigation key/property name convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#conventions) (the foreign key property name is foreign navigation property name with the suffix "Id"), then you can just remove the ForeignKeyAttribute and EF Core will automatically do the work.